# .val nao funciona em button submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um botão de submit com um span dentro:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar justify-content-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-loading">
      <span class="circle"></span> Próxima etapa
    </button>
  </div>
```

e queria mudar o texto dele quando estiver enviando, porem quando eu uso o `.val` não acontece nada. Porem se eu usar `.text` ele muda o texto mas tira o `<span>` e é preciso que ele continue. 
Meu JS ( já esta dentro de document ready ):

```
var btnsubmit = $(":submit");
var loadingcircle = $("span.circle");
loadingcircle.show();
btnsubmit.prop('disabled', true).val("Validando CNPJ");
```

Comment: Você pode usar o comando `.html` escrevendo o `span` com o texto desejado.

Comment: `.val()` Não funciona para isto, este método do jQuery é para pegar valores de elementos de formulários, como inputs, selects, etc... Não para pegar texto de botão!

Comment: Igor, `.val`, como o "nome" já diz, é para atributo `value=`, obviamente não se aplica ao seu caso (não tem value no seu button). @RobertoBraga seria legal postar como resposta, assim fecharia a questão

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temos alguns pontos a considerar:

1- O uso da função `val()`  não é viável nesse caso pois o seu `button` não tem o atributo `value`.

2- Usando `text()` você conseguirá mudar o `texto` do botão, porém, todo conteúdo que tiver dentro dele será sobrescrito.

Uma solução: Usar a função [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html).

Mesmo assim o conteúdo que estiver no botão será sobrescrito, para isso, basta adicionar novamente seu `span` e após inserir o texto pretendido.

Ficará assim:

```js
$('.btn-loading').on('click', function(){
    $(this).html("<span class='circle'></span> Carregando...");
});
```

```css
.circle:before {
  content: "♦";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-toolbar justify-content-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-loading">
      <span class="circle"></span> Próxima etapa
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!